# Finding The Super Class of a class just before Top Class with Jena

Tags: jena, ontology, owl

I am using jena framework to process my owl ontology.

I want to write a method which can find the super class it belongs which is just under the Thing class.

Four example, if there are 5 level hierarchy, lets say first level is Thing, second level is secondAncestor, third level is ThirdAncestor and so on. If I pass a class FifthAncestor, I want to return SecondAncestor because Thing does not make any sense.  If I pass ThirdAncestor, I want to return SecondAncestor. In other words, most general class it belongs to but not the top one (Thing).

Answer (score 1):

**Method one**

This will depend on your model having a reasoner, because `owl:Thing` isn't normally asserted into a model, and so won't be present in a model with no reasoner. Given that, then:

```
OntModel m = ... your OntModel ...;
OntClass thing = m.getOntClass( OWL.Thing.getURI() );
for (Iterator<OntClass> i = thing.listSubClasses(true); i.hasNext(); ) {
    OntClass hierarchyRoot = i.next();
    ....
}
```

Note the use of the flag `direct = true` in the `listSubClasses()` call.

**Method two**

Does not require a reasoner.

```
for (Iterator<OntClass> i = m.listHierarchyRootClasses(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    OntClass hierarchyRoot = i.next();
    ....
}
```

Note that this method will return the root classes, even if they are anonymous resources representing a class expression. For UI purposes, this often isn't what you want (it's hard to display a bNode in a meaningful way to a user). In this case, use [OntTools.namedHierarchyRoots](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntTools.html#namedHierarchyRoots%28com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel%29) instead.

**Update**

I now understand that Alan wants the root classes that are parents of a particular class, whereas `namedHierarchyRoots` will list *all* of the root classes of the class hierarchy. Note that, in general, a class may have zero, one or many named-superclasses between it and `Thing`.

Anyway, here's how I would solve this. Again, this solution assumes the model is *not* using a reasoner. With a reasoner, it would be much easier:

```
private boolean hasSubClassTransitive( OntClass parent, OntClass child ) {
    return OntTools.findShortestPath( child.getOntModel(), child, parent,
                                      new OntTools.PredicateFilter( RDFS.subClassOf ) ) != null;
}

public List<OntClass> namedRootsOf( OntClass c ) {
    List<OntClass> cRoots = new ArrayList<OntClass>();
    for (OntClass root: OntTools.namedHierarchyRoots( c.getOntModel() )) {
        if (hasSubClassTransitive( root, c )) {
            cRoots.add( root );
        }
    }
    return cRoots;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution in following way without using reasoner. It is not perfect solution but it works. This solution also solves problem, if you get unnamed (anonymous) class as super class.

First I created an array which stores top level class names.

A simple method which searches in my created array, if the passed parameter is a top class.

```
public Boolean IsTopClass(String ontologyClass)
  {
              //NS is URI of ontology
      String onClass=ontologyClass.replace(NS, "");

      for(String oClass: topLevelClassList)
      {
          if(oClass.equalsIgnoreCase(onClass))
              return true;
      }
      return false;

  }
```

Then the main method which finds most general class under thing:

```
      public String FindSuperClassUnderThing(OntClass subClass)
  {

     OntClass prevSubClass=subClass;
     OntClass prevprevSubClass=null;         

     String topClass="";

     String supClass=subClass.toString();
     ExtendedIterator<OntClass> superClassList=null;
    while(!this.IsTopClass(topClass))
    {   
        prevprevSubClass=prevSubClass;
        prevSubClass=prevSubClass.getSuperClass();
                    //if returned class is a anonymous class (not a named one)
                    //get list of superclasses and check if there is a topclass
                    //inside the super class list
        if(!prevSubClass.toString().startsWith(NS))
        {
            prevSubClass=prevprevSubClass;
             superClassList= prevSubClass.listSuperClasses();

             while(superClassList.hasNext())
                {
                   OntClass OntClassFromList= superClassList.next();
                    if(this.IsTopClass(OntClassFromList.toString()))
                    {
                    topClass= OntClassFromList.toString();
                    }
                }

        }
        else
        {
            if (this.IsTopClass(prevSubClass.toString()))
            {
                topClass= prevSubClass.toString();
            }
        }


    }

     return topClass;
}
```

Comment: This seems a lot more convoluted than either of the two solutions I gave. In general, you do not need to do String manipulation for equality testing in Jena. What features of your problem does your solution solve better?

Comment: Actually I could not figure out how to use your solution. I want to go bottom to top, your suggestion will run from top to bottom. I am not sure that it suits what I asked. I am not expert of Jena, it probably caused to create messy code. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah, you want *just* the root classes for a given class, and not all of them. OK, I can update my solution.